# Using Javascript RegEx, how find a word that's not inside a multi-line or single-line comment or inside quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all instances of the word "class" that:

1. Is preceded by either a line beg or white space
2. Is followed only by one or more whites
3. Is *not* inside a single or multi-line comment

How would I do this?

My original regex was: `new RegEx( "(^|\\s+)class\\s+", "g" )` but this also finds things in comments. How would I alter it to ignore commented instances?

Comment: Stripping all the comments out of the string and then running your regex on that could be a clean solution, or are you looking for something that's purely regex?

Comment: You need a parser specific to the language codes you need to omit comments of, otherwise a regex wouldn't be an ultimate solution [**`(?://.*|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/)|\s+(class)`**](https://regex101.com/r/kdLTzU/1)

Comment: @Kamehameha unfortunately, it has to be 100% regex

Comment: @revo What do you mean? This is JavaScript parsing other JavaScript code (all written in UTF-8)

Comment: @DonRhummy Sorry, I meant a regex only solution. You can replace all the comments with an empty string. Then you can use the above regex to fetch the class. All in javascript :)

Comment: @Kamehameha No he can't.

Comment: Then  you need a JS parser / tokenizer. E.g [esprima](http://esprima.org)

Comment: @revo Would that allow me to replace the instances not in comments, but still retain the comments when i save it back into a file?

Comment: @DonRhummy I have been here for 3 years, and although most users tell to use a parser, I do not remember seeing such an answer - all are regex based. Use revo's regex to match the comments and capture the class, and when replacing use some logic in the callback method.

Comment: what do you mean by a `line beg`?

Comment: @Udo Beginning of the line `^`

Comment: @Udo I have *never* heard anyone call it a wedge and I think asking about a beginning of a line is clear. I have no idea why you're being so rude and condescending about it.

Comment: @DonRhummy my bad, I had no intention to come off as rude or condescending, it was just a bit unclear for me.